# spring cloud contracts gradle runs tests every time

Tags: spring, testing, gradle, cloud, contract

Normally when you run gradle test twice you will get UP-TO-DATE the second time.
My problem is that when using spring cloud contracts, generated-test-sources are rebuild each time so all tests are run again. It looks like gradle runs task :generateContractTests every time. Why ? Can I do something with that ?

Answer (score 0):

If that task is written by you, check the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks) on how to make a task compatible with incremental builds.

If that task is produced by a plugin, check the plugin documentation if their task supports up-to-date checks. If not, consider filing an enhancement request on the plugin.

Comment: my question is related to https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/multi/multi__spring_cloud_contract_verifier_setup.html

Comment: If you are able to, run a build scan and see why the task is not up to date. https://guides.gradle.org/creating-build-scans/